# How can I do for Rijndael-256 with BouncyCastle API?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, rijndael

An ancient PHP guy wrote encryption code for `Rijndael-256 (!AES256) / ECB / NoPadding`.

I tried this.

```
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(
        new RijndaelEngine(256), new ZeroBytePadding());
cipher.init(encrypt, new KeyParameter(Arrays.copyOf(KEY.getBytes(UTF_8), 16)));
byte[] source = supplier.get();
byte[] target = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(source.length)];
int offset = cipher.processBytes(source, 0, source.length, target, 0);
cipher.doFinal(target, offset);
```

But encryption always adds paddings. Yes I know I used `ZeroBytePadding`.

How can I solve this? I failed to find any good references.

Comment: The plaintext length *must be* a multiple of the block size, in this case 32 bytes. Padding schemes ensure that this occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the encryption really didn't add padding, then just initialise the cipher as:

```
new BufferedBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(256))
```

Be aware that the `doFinal` call will throw a `DataLengthException` if the data you are trying to decrypt is not actually block-aligned.

BTW, it's also a good habit to check the return value of `doFinal` (how many bytes were output), since `getOutputSize` is allowed to be an overestimate.

Comment: I'm not sure but I found it's the `InvalidCipherTextException` that I should care of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing my (possible) solution based on the accepted answer.

```
BufferedBlockCipher cipher =
    new BufferedBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(256));
cipher.init(encrypt, new KeyParameter(Arrays.copyOf(KEY.getBytes(UTF_8), 16)));
byte[] source = supplier.get();
byte[] target = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(source.length)];
int offset = cipher.processBytes(source, 0, source.length, target, 0);
try {
    offset += cipher.doFinal(target, offset);
} catch (InvalidCipherTextException icte) {
    // if padding is expected and not found
    //throw new RuntimeException(icte);
}
target = Arrays.copyOf(target, offset);
```

I'm not sure, though.

Comment: This code is still creating "new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(...)" but it should be creating "new BufferedBlockCipher(...)" as given in my answer.